# How can I use asyncore with the multiprocessing IPC module in Python 3?

Tags: python, sockets, event-handling, multiprocessing, asyncore

I'm trying to utilise the Client/Server architecture of the `multiprocessing` module to facilitate communication between my Python scripts. I want to be able to implement a separate connection listener apart from my main event loop, using `asyncore`. How can I do this?

While there is no outward documentation of how to do so, I've tried to construct a basic `asyncore.dispatcher` using the listener socket from `multiprocessing.Listener`:

```
import asyncore
import socket
from multiprocessing.connection import Listener, Client

class ConnectionListener(asyncore.dispatcher):
    def __init__(self, ln):
        asyncore.dispatcher.__init__(self)
        self.set_socket(ln._listener._socket)
    def handle_accepted(self, sock, addr):
        print("Accepted a client!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    address = ('localhost', 19378)
    try:
        ln = Listener(address)
        x = ConnectionListener(ln)
        while True:
            asyncore.loop()
    except socket.error:
        c = Client(address)
        print("Client is trying to connect")
```

While the server does loop, it never fires `handle_accepted`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the method you are are looking for is handle_accept, not handle_accepted.